# Trouble using MongoDB as backend for Django project (Django 1.7)

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I set up my app using the following tutorial,
http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html
When I set my backend as detailed in this link in my settings.py, I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseIntrospection may require
a  get_table_list() method
```

I have installed all the necessary packages (django-nonrel, djangotoolbox, mongodb-engine), but I'm still getting these errors. What might I be doing wrong/am I missing? It could very likely be something trivial-- I'm new to Django and MongoDB.

My DATABASES setting is as follows,

```
DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'example_db'
   }
}
```

and my INSTALLED_APPS are as follows,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mongoadmin',
    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
    'polls', 
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include your full DATABASES setting from settings.py?

Comment: And your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I've added both above. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

django-mongo-db-engine does not work with Django 1.7. It uses 
Django-nonrel, (a fork of Django) *instead* of Django.

Try creating your dev environment again, but this time, do not install Django 1.7.

Comment: This works! Do I need to run migrate or makemigration now that I'm switching to MongoDB? I'm unable to log into my admin page.

Comment: The [instructions you linked to](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/setup.html) are using the version of Django-nonrel based on Django 1.5. The `migrate` and `makemigration` commands were only introduced in Django 1.7. However, since you're using MongoDB, you shouldn't have to do schema migrations anyway.