# django1.7 with mongodb issue?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am getting this error when I run
`python manage.py runserver`:

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 179, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.get_table_list(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 1383, in get_table_list
    raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of BaseDatabaseIntrospection may require a get_table_list() method')
NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseIntrospection may require a get_table_list() method
```

Comment: how duplicated?and where is the privous question?

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988670/trouble-using-mongodb-as-backend-for-django-project-django-1-7). As I said in that answer, django-mongo-db-engine does not work with Django 1.7. The [mongo-db-engine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine) repository has not been updated for some time, so I wouldn't recommend using it either. You shouldn't be using Django 1.7, it is unsupported and insecure.